# Find a irrep from Character Table

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

I have been studying Group Theory from P. Ramond's book and I already googled a lot but I could not find the answer or a procedural to find what procedure Ramond uses in the image below.

[image]

So, my question is how does he manage to find this irrep for 3?
Any help it will be, certainly, appreciate it.

Comment: He gave a concrete matrix for the representation in (3.77) so just take the trace to get the last representation $\chi^{[3]}$. There are ways to obtain this character without giving explicit representation by doing $\pi-id$ where $\pi$ is a character obtained by counting the number of fixed points although this maybe something further along in the book.

Comment: my question, specifically, is: how does he find this matrix from the character table?